# XmlInclude in Unii test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to use `XmlInclude` in a unit test (in a visual studio test project) and I am getting the weird error message `CS1729; 'XmlIgnoreAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`. In a non-unit-test project that code compiles fine. Does anyone know why?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAndExplore()
    {
        Test x = new Test();
        Serialization.SerializeToXmlString(x);
    }

    public class Test : ModelBase { public Base Base { get; set; } = new Derived(); }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
    public class Base { }
    public class Derived : Base { }
```

Comment: Problem has nothing to do with XmlInclude.  You have XmlIgnoreAttribute in you code that you did post.

Comment: Hm. I have this: `[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]`

Comment: what is wrong with that line?  Nothing.

Comment: Yes, but it gives the CS1729 error message when used in a unit test project.

Comment: Are you doing following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes, it is a `[TestMethod]` in a Visual Studio unit test project.